# Widevine DRM on Windows 8 modern app is it possible?

Tags: windows-8, drm

We need to play Widevine or/and Verimatrix DRM content on Windows 8 modern application. Will we have some problems with this? If yes, what are the solutions to achieve this goal? Will we need to buy some more product?

Comment: What kind of _problems_ ?

Comment: Windows 8 native player supports PlayReady DRM. And customer do not want to buy it too. We need a way to play content sequred by Widevine DRM on windows 8. For example we found NexPlayer SDK which can play Verimatrix DRM content on Windows 8 as I understand.

Comment: We didn't try to do something, we only want to know is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

According to their site, [Widevine support Microsoft Windows](http://www.widevine.com/supported_platforms.html), but I didn't find any explicit mention of Windows 8 there.

However, to the best of my knowledge they have been supporting Windows 8 almost right from the start.

For an official answer, you should just ask them directly.